# How would it be written using REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I am making a browser game, it's completely AJAX-based, so I am trying to create a proper RESTful API.
So, I have a `User` model (basically, `User` has weapon, health and action points).
So I have a `users` resource. Now, I want to implement user attacks.
Scenario: user with id = `1` attacks user with id = `2`.
What I would do is like this:

1. Send the following info (with POST-request):

   - target_id (well, it's stored in ApplicationController from session)
   - attacker_id
   - weapon_id (weapon attacker uses to attack his target)
     to `/users/attacker_id/attack/`
2. Validate if user has enough action points and health for attack, if target is not dead yet. If these conditions fail - do nothing, if they succeed - decrease attackers action points and ammo, decrease target HP. All of this is done in model method called `attack` for attacker.

Is it a proper way in general or if there is a better, Rails way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST really makes the most sense when what you're doing are resource-based CRUD interactions. You're not really doing that in this case--you can sort of conceptually force it to conform, but I think you'd end up adding unnecessary and unintuitive complexity.

I'd say you just don't use REST. Just have an attack action that takes the params and does the rest.